# Codeigniter ORM active_record example generator sql WHERE id ='1' AND ( c1 like '%3%' OR c2 like '%3%' )

Tags: sql, codeigniter, activerecord, orm, codeigniter-datamapper

With CodeIgniter ORM active_record as I can generate the SQL for example ..?

Example generator SQL: **... AND( LIKE ... OR LIKE ...)**

```
SELECT id, c1, c2 FORM t1 WHERE id ='1' AND ( c1 LIKE '%3%' OR c2 LIKE '%3%' )
```

Enccontre not in the form of combiar ORM functions to generate something like what I show in the SQL instance.

What is this but most perished is not what I want.

```
$this->db->select('id, c1, c2')
                ->from('t1')
                ->where('id', '1111')
                ->like('c1',$sSearch)
                ->or_like('c2',$sSearch)
                ->get();
```

Answer (score 1):

When mixing `AND` and `OR`, parenthesis are your friend.  CodeIgniter's active record doesn't support mixing `AND` and `OR` like you want.

CodeIgniter will output the following query:

```
SELECT id, c1, c2 FORM t1 WHERE id ='1' AND c1 LIKE '%3%' OR c2 LIKE '%3%'
```

Obviously, this is not what you want.  What you can do is: pass a custom string to `WHERE` to use that as the clause.

```php
// Since we are using a custom string, we need to escape manually
$sSearch = $this->db->escape_like_str($sSearch);
$this->db->select('id, c1, c2')
            ->from('t1')
            ->where('id', '1')
            // this will add the clause like you want
            ->where("(`c1` LIKE '%$sSearch%' OR `c2` LIKE '%$sSearch%')", NULL, FALSE)
            ->get();
```

This will output the query you want:

```
SELECT id, c1, c2 FORM t1 WHERE id ='1' AND (c1 LIKE '%3%' OR c2 LIKE '%3%')
```

Answer (score 0):

Since your english is hard to understand i'm taking a stab at this...

I am assuming you are trying to use LIKE with the wildcard `%` before, or after the keyword..

you can do this by using before, after, both(default) within the like or or_like..

```
<?php
$this->db
     ->select('id, c1, c2')
     ->from('t1')
     ->where('id', '1111')
      //$this->db->like('title', 'match', 'before'); 
      //Produces: WHERE title LIKE '%match'  
      //$this->db->like('title', 'match', 'after'); 
      //Produces: WHERE title LIKE 'match%' 
      //$this->db->like('title', 'match', 'both'); 
      //Produces: WHERE title LIKE '%match%'
     ->like('c1', $sSearch)
     ->or_like('c2', $sSearch)
     ->get();
```

---

Or you can execute with raw sql - http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/queries.html

```
<?php $this->db->query("YOUR SEQUEL STATEMENT HERE");
```